# why is "get()" necessary in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to understand this example from [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/end/#example-0) 
in this snippet

```
        var tags = this.map(function () {
        return this.tagName;
    })
            .get().join(", ");
```

why get() is necessary? 
in the [api](http://api.jquery.com/get/) it says that get() Retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object. In this case, I see that get() is not applied to jq object, but on strings.
When I remove get(), I get this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'join'

why join can not work with map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Here, `this` is jQuery object with a list of nodes. (All functions in `jQuery.fn` have their context (i.e.,`this`) set to the jQuery object that is making the call to the function.)
- The call to [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) returns a jQuery object with a list of strings. (You may be confusing jQuery's `map` function with the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) array function introduced in ECMAScript 5,)
- The call to `get` returns a plain JS array of those strings, and `join` acts on that array.

The call to `get` is necessary to transform the jQuery object with a list of strings (returned by `map`) into a plain JS array so it can be glued together with `join`.

Answer (score 0):

`join` is for arrays  ( pure js arrays) .

your function returns jquery array which needs to be translated to js plain

`.Get()`  - does that.

http://api.jquery.com/get/

> Retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object.

[image]

Comment: "return this.tagName; " is this jq object?

Comment: @AladdinHoms No, but the result of calling `.map()` is a jQuery object. The call to `.get()` creates a native Javascript array from the elements (in this case, text nodes) inside that jQuery object, which allows you to use `join()`, which is a native Javascript function of arrays, not a jQuery function.

Comment: Join is actually an array function, and get returns the array equivalent of the jQuery object holding *strings*.

Comment: @Yoshi You're right, I was just re-reading my comment and wondering why on earth I said text nodes, because that's not what I wanted to say at all.